# Package installed but not detected (pip3.2)

Tags: package-management

I'm trying to install pip to install BeatutifulSoup4 against python3.3. Linux Mint 16.

```
[127]manuel@manuel-X202E:~ > pip3.2 install beautifulsoup4
No command 'pip3.2' found, did you mean:
 Command 'pip-3.2' from package 'python3-pip' (universe)
 pip3.2: command not found
---------------------
[100]manuel@manuel-X202E:~ > sudo apt-get install python3-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-pip is already the newest version.
----------------------
manuel@manuel-X202E:~ > pip-3.2 install beautifulsoup4
The program 'pip-3.2' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

so, the package is installed but it's not detected (I  tried to restart OS)

---

I also tried:

```
 sudo apt-get purge python3-pip 
 sudo apt-get install python3-pip 
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get check
```

As well as

```
 sudo apt-get purge python3-pip 
 (reinstall via Synaptic)
```

**EDIT**: I finally solved (using dpkg) . The problem was that I should use

```
 pip3
```

instead of

```
pip3-2
```

Comment: List the files in the package. This is usually a reliable indication this those files are present on your system, but you can always check if you want to. Check for `/usr/bin/pip-3.2`. I just installed this on my system, and that file is listed, and `pip-3.2` runs. Use `dpkg -L python3-pip`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your question I think, your problem is just a typo - the correct command is **pip-3.2, not** just **pip3.2**.

**EDIT:** Ok then, if the typo wasn't the main bad guy, let's try something else...

1) Uninstall *python3-pip*

```
sudo apt-get purge python3-pip
```

2) Clean everything :-)

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get remove
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

3) Install *python3-pip*, update your package list and check dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get check
```

4) If this does not work, try to reinstall it using Synaptic

5) If you still had no luck, try

```
dpkg -L python3-pip
```

and look for files located in */usr/bin* if there isn't other launchable file instead of *pip-3.2*

Comment: it's true that it is pip-3.2 . However it doesn't work anyway (please see my updated answer).

Comment: I just tried both. No way the problem is solved. I also checked very carefully the commands

Comment: I finally found (by using dpkg) that I should use "pip3" (instead of pip-3.2) which worked. thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! And here we see, that we can't fully trust Error messages :-) Add please this solution to your question, to make it easier for somebody new to find ;-)